# how to remove circles from javafx pane when clicked

Tags: java, javafx

I have an assignment for school where i have to make a pane and then make circles appear when i click them, and then remove them with right clicked. this is what i have so far

```
pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    Circle clicky = new Circle();
    if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
        pane.getChildren().remove(1, 1);
    } else if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
        clicky.setRadius(5);
        clicky.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        clicky.setStroke(BLACK);
        clicky.setCenterX(e.getX());
        clicky.setCenterY(e.getY());
        pane.getChildren().addAll(clicky);
    }
});
```

what I've written so far won't remove circles, just make them. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: thank you. that was exactly what i needed. should i delete this or is it being marked as duplicate basically the same to outsiders?

Comment: There's basically no need for your entire class to post the exact same question to start with.

Comment: they aren't? as far as i know